# How to attach a file from ipad in your application?

Tags: objective-c

I have developed an application in ipad, i want to browse a file from ipad and attach it to my apps..it should not be like e-mail attachment..am sorting out the code but am gettin code for only email attachment

Answer (score 0):

The only files on the iPad your app will be allowed to browse are the files inside your app's sandbox or those accessed using a framework like the [Assets Library Framework](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/AssetsLibrary/Reference/AssetsLibraryFramework/_index.html). As for "attaching a file to your apps", what do you mean by that? Can you clarify?